# Paper ink animation flickers

Tags: polymer

I seem to come across this issue on two of my projects.  I have paper ink animations on checkboxes, which I have not altered the css. and the ink animations seem to flicker when I click the checkbox.  The demos dont seem to do this.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks,
David

Comment: I have this same problem with the paper-fab element. Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve the problem in a new project. You will need to add this to your css where the element is being clicked:

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);